# where do I use access token?

Tags: android, twitter, gson

I want to use twitter json parse with gson. I register as developer and I create a new project on dev. twitter web site but I dont know how can I use this access token in my android project?Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Almost 10 seconds of search on Google :
http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html